# Upload XML file and pass into array stored in cookie

Tags: php, xml

I've seen snippets of code on how to create an associative array from an XML file, however I'm unsure on how to have a system where the user can upload their own XML file, and it creates the associative array from the uploaded file and then stores the array inside of a cookie.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nothing as of yet, I'm just looking for a good method on how it could be done. Otherwise I'll probably mess around for hours and end up doing it completely wrong :P

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be an associative array? Otherwise you could check out [simplexml_load_file($filename)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Comment: Not necessarily, I thought that would be the usual way to store something like this. Can you pull elements and such from the object created from this function like you do in an array?

Comment: Yeah sure, only instead of $array['key'] you do it like $array->key

Comment: So I could use simplexml_load($file) and have $file as $_FILES['xml_file'] for example?

Comment: You could do that from the tmpname from the file ($_FILES['xml_file']['tmp_name']), but save the file to a more permanent path first http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Big Ginger Nerd's suggestion:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

This converts it to JSON and then back to an associative array.  +1 to Big Ginger Nerd and the suggestions on the [PHP SimpleXML manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#105330).

Comment: I'll give this a crack :)

Comment: If it works for you, be sure to give Big Ginger Nerd a +1 before I get one.  He put the foundation under this.